# Can sound be turned off in MediaRecorder of the Android API?

Tags: android, mediarecorder

I would like to write a program that records video but **not** sound.

Can anyone help me on how to not record the sound while recording the video using MediaRecorder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed possible. See the [setAudioEncoder method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#setAudioEncoder%28int%29) in MediaRecorder:

> If this method is not called, the output file will not contain an audio track.

So if you only want video, simply do not invoke this method.

Comment: No if that fonction is not called, it will crash with the error: IllegalState exception

Comment: @daivuk I haven't tested or researched this in over 3 years, so it's possible that the API has changed in the meantime. However, are you sure that you are not calling `setAudioEncoder()` before calling `setOutputFormat()` or calling `setAudioEncoder()` after calling `prepare()`? The documentation states that doing either of those things will throw an `IllegalStateException`.

Answer (score 0):

You should just prepare your mediarecorder's video requirements, like:

```
private boolean prepareMediaRecorder(){
    myCamera = getCameraInstance();
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();        


 // store the quality profile required
    CamcorderProfile profile = CamcorderProfile.get(mCameraId, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);

    myCamera.unlock();
    mediaRecorder.setCamera(myCamera);

    mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(profile.fileFormat);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(profile.videoCodec);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(profile.videoBitRate);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(profile.videoFrameRate);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(profile.videoFrameWidth, profile.videoFrameHeight);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/myvideo.mp4");
    mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(60000 * 20); // Set max duration 60 *20 sec.
    mediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(5000000 * 4); // Set max file size 5M * 4

    mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(myCameraSurfaceView.getHolder().getSurface());

    try {
        mediaRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    }
    return true;

}
```